# How to get all hidden objects by script?

Tags: python, scripting

I selected some objects in outliner, all of them are hidden. Now I want to know how to get these objects?
I tried using `bpy.context.selected_objects` , but it prints an empty array `[]`.

I know I can use `bpy.context.object` to get one object, but I don’t know if there is a way to get all hidden objects？

Comment: You can use https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selected_ids but it's only available in the context of the outliner. (your button must be clicked in the outliner)

Comment: @Gorgious thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this one out, but how about selecting all objects in the scene, and then only keep objects with state set to hidden?

```
import bpy 
# get all objects
all_objects = bpy.data.objects[:]

# keep only objects that are hidden
hidden_objects = [obj for obj in all_objects if obj.hide_viewport == True]
```

Answer (score 1):

`context.selected_objects` and `context.selectable_objects` return only objects that are visible in viewport because an invisible object is no longer valid as selected in the data, even if it´s marked darker in the Outliner.

When a selected object is made invisible (hidden or disabled) and switched visible again, it seems to be selected in Outliner but the yellow (selection) border in the 3DView is missing. The object can´t be modified (e.g. hold, rotate, scale) until it has been reselected.

In Outliner there are two ways to make an object invisible:

`Hide in Viewport` (Symbol Eye) and
`Disable in Viewports` (Symbol Monitor - filter disabled by default)

Note that 'Hide in Viewport' (Eye) is an attribute of `LayerCollection` and 'Disable in Viewports' (Monitor) an attribute of `(Data)Collection`.
See the first two entries here: [link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=hide_viewport&check_keywords=yes&area=default#)

There are different ways to get invisible, hidden or disabled objects, depending on what is desired:

```
import bpy 

# get invisible objs (hidden or disabled) by different of context.visible_objects
invisible_objs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if not o in bpy.context.visible_objects]
print("invisible (eye or monitor):", invisible_objs)

# get hidden objs by viewlayer.objects
hidden_objs = [o for o in bpy.context.view_layer.objects if o.hide_get() is True]
print("hidden (eye):", hidden_objs)

# get disabled objs by data.objects
disabled_objs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.hide_viewport == True]
print("disabled (monitor):", disabled_objs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get all selected objects, whether they are hidden or not.

```
def GetAllSelectedObjects():
    visibles = bpy.context.visible_objects
    bpy.ops.object.hide_view_clear()
    selecteds = bpy.context.selected_objects
    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        if not o in visibles:
            o.hide_set(True)
    return selecteds
```